# how to make drop down list in one div to overlap alternate div

Tags: html

I have two alternate divisions.The first division is having a list of options.Initially i set the overflow property for the first division as overflow:hidden..When i hover over any option a drop down list gets displayed at the right of the hovered item overlapping the alternate division.
 But when i add scroll bar in the first division with overflow:scroll property and then hover over any option in the list, the drop down list appear on the right of the hovered item but does not overlap the alternate division.It gets hidden behind the scroll bar and to see the drop down list i need to scroll the horizontal scroll bar in the first division.

I want the drop down list to get displayed over the scroll bar not behind it and overlap the alternate division.
      Can any body tell me why is this happening....and what to do?

Comment: Try `overflow:auto`. Besides that we'll have to see more code to help

Comment: overflow:auto is also causing the same problem.Is there any other idea for displaying the hidden drop down menu in an overlapping form over the alternate division

Comment: Provide your other code and perhaps we can help

Comment: @zeaklous my code is very lengthy,this comment box is not accepting it,so iam sending it to your mail,u will recieve the mail from "heynitish717@gmail.com"

Comment: I only received the HTML of the project, so there is no effects or positioning at all. I'm sorry, I can't be able to help with this